# Count number of leaves in tree?

Tags: python, tree, graph-theory

I am trying to implement counting leaves in trees (not necessarily binary trees) in an efficient manner.

I have an edge input file like this (with two branches, thus two leaves):

[image]

```
# nodeID     treeID    parentID level M
8915218131 11994463802 9019194630 84 1152
8915218132 11994463802 9019194631 84 1018
9019194630 11994463802 9122013305 85 1152
9122013305 11994463802 9224080882 86 1152
9122013306 11994463802 9224080883 86 1009
9224080882 11994463802 9325374898 87 1153
9325374898 11994463802 9426419957 88 1153
9426419957 11994463802 9526231677 89 1153
9526231677 11994463802 9625289594 90 1153
9625289594 11994463802 9723827035 91 1154
9723827035 11994463802 9822081910 92 1154
9822081910 11994463802 9919855221 93 1154
9919855221 11994463802 10017373825 94 1154
10017373825 11994463802 10114414643 95 1154
10114414643 11994463802 10211212821 96 1154
10114414644 11994463802 10211212822 96 1000
10211212821 11994463802 10307531761 97 1154
10307531761 11994463802 10403632357 98 1154
10403632357 11994463802 10499245188 99 1154
10499245188 11994463802 10594618828 100 1154
10594618828 11994463802 10689537668 101 1154
10689537668 11994463802 10784230758 102 1154
10784230758 11994463802 10878482733 103 1154
10878482733 11994463802 10972591178 104 1154
10972591178 11994463802 11066270407 105 1154
11066270407 11994463802 11159769310 106 1154
11159769310 11994463802 11252883435 107 1154
11252883435 11994463802 11345851308 108 1154
11345851308 11994463802 11438596137 109 1153
11438596137 11994463802 11531494001 110 1153
11531494001 11994463802 11624604030 111 1153
11624604030 11994463802 11718806817 112 1153
11718806817 11994463802 11811844824 113 1152
11811844824 11994463802 11904133551 114 1141
11904133551 11994463802 11994463802 115 1139
11994463802 11994463802 -1          116 1140
```

As you can see, the last line is the root (always level 116). In this case there are two leaves.

I need to filter the tree for `M > 1100` (OK for all here) and count the number of leaves, for millions of such trees. This makes graph libraries like NetworkX a bit problematic, because constructing a tree takes too long.

My current approach to count leaves is to just count nodes which do not have any edge pointing to them. Below is my current code. Is there any tool or technique I could use that is better?

My current Python code:

```
import sys
from operator import itemgetter
Mmin = 1100

def handle(tree, treeid, Mfinal):
    # sort by levelid, if input not already presorted
    #tree.sort(itemgetter(3))
    nleafs = 0
    nonleaf = set()
    for id, rootid, parentid, layerid, M in tree:
        if M >= Mmin:
            nonleaf.add(parentid)
            if id not in nonleaf:
                nleafs += 1
    print(treeid, Mfinal, nleafs)
    sys.stdout.flush()

Mfinal = None
lasttreeid = None
tree = []
for l in sys.stdin:
    parts = l.strip().split()
    id, treeid, parentid, levelid, M = parts
    if lastrootid != treeid:
        if Mfinal is not None and Mfinal > Mmin and snapnum == "116":
            handle(tree, lasttreeid, Mfinal)
        tree = []
        lasttreeid = treeid
        Mfinal = None
    if parentid == '-1':
        Mfinal = int(M)
    tree.append((id, treeid, parentid, int(levelid), int(M)))
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see where it's actually spending most of its time?

Comment: Huh, looks like most time is spent in simply parsing the text input, and almost nothing in handling the graph!

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to collect all nodes and substract from them nodes that are parents. It is the easiest to implement it with sets and set difference operation.

```
def leaves(filename):
    lasttreeid = None
    nodes = set()
    parents = set()
    for l in open(filename):
        nodeid, treeid, parentid, levelid, M = l.strip().split()
        if lasttreeid is None:
            lasttreeid = treeid
        if lasttreeid != treeid:
            print 'Tree %s, number of leaves %d' % (lasttreeid, len(nodes - parents))
            lasttreeid = treeid
            nodes = set()
            parents = set()
        nodes.add(nodeid)
        parents.add(parentid)
    print 'Tree %s, number of leaves %d' % (lasttreeid, len(nodes - parents))
```